# Expression Engine 1.7.1 new page generating {segment_3_category_name} tag instead of content

Tags: structure, ee1, workflow

Yes, its an old version of EE. I take no responsibility for this. 
Trying to create a new page, but every time we save a revision and go to Live Look (or go straight to the page on the live site), all of the text from the Body and/or Extended text fields are lumped into the right side-bar, and the "body" of the page just shows:
**{segment_3_category_name}**
Coming Soon! Please check back later. 
Active plugins include Structure and Workflow. 
First question here, I'm assuming I'm missing critical information, so please feel free to yell at me for missing something obvious. :D

Comment: That variable indicates that you have the [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) extension installed. Make sure it's active and enabled for your category group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. Looks like it was an issue between the Page URL and the URL title not matching in the Structure tab. I originally had the URL set to "newstudentoffer" and the URL Title set to new_student_offer. That mismatch was throwing off the system. After I made the URL new_student_offer, everything showed up correctly and the {Segment_3_category_name} tag disappeared.